# Tracing transform() within XSLT

Tags: saxon

I have a variable that holds the results of a transform()

```
<xsl:variable name="wqml" select="transform(map{'stylesheet-location':$xsl, 'source-node':$xml})?output"/>
```

When tracing this XSLT in Saxon, there is a "variable wqml" row that shows the total time.  Is a way for the analysis to also break down the time spent within the transform?

Answer (score 0):

We raised an issue on this a few days ago: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5681

What we observed was that the report did cover the "secondary" transformations, but they were not clearly identified as such. If you're getting a different effect, could you please report it on that issue tracker?

Comment: Done.  I reported my XSLT instructions and the profile.html